# how to obtain a model of a parent model with information obtained from a service

Tags: java, android

I learn to use Web services, I have a service which I can obtain in a model without problem, but this model has subClasses as RESULT that in turn contains PRODUCTS and FEE which in JSON language are objects, my problem is that I need to obtain the information stored in the model PRODUCT that is inside the RESULT class and I have no idea how to do it, it is complicated ah at this point, I leave the service hoping they can help me, I must clarify that my Java model has been created correctly.

```
{
"links": {
    "previous": null,
    "next": null
},
"results": [
    {
        "created_at": "2018-08-29T15:52:29.175042Z",
        "total_amount": "700.00",
        "reference_number": "CD1006",
        "is_fee": true,
        "id": 47,
        "products": [
            {
                "price": "150.00",
                "description": "Description",
                "discount": "150.00",
                "pin_code": "IS73DR",
                "is_billable": false,
                "contract": null,
                "product_type": 1,
                "sale": 47,
                "attribute_product": {
                    "id": 100,
                    "plan_name": "Express",
                    "is_chosen": false,
                    "is_active": true,
                    "validity_months": 1,
                    "query_quantity": 1,
                    "available_queries": 1,
                    "expiration_date": null
                },
                "product_type_name": "Planes de Consulta"
            },
            {
                "price": "700.00",
                "description": "Description",
                "discount": "0.00",
                "pin_code": "VIKDBE",
                "is_billable": true,
                "contract": null,
                "product_type": 1,
                "sale": 47,
                "attribute_product": {
                    "id": 101,
                    "plan_name": "Express Duo",
                    "is_chosen": false,
                    "is_active": false,
                    "validity_months": 3,
                    "query_quantity": 2,
                    "available_queries": 2,
                    "expiration_date": null
                },
                "product_type_name": "Planes de Consulta"
            }
        ],
        "fee": {
            "fee_amount": "150.00",
            "fee_order_number": 1,
            "fee_quantity": 1,
            "pay_before": "2018-09-01",
            "status": 1,
            "id": 43
        }
    }
],
"count": 1,
"total_pages": 1
}
```

this is the model :

```
public class ContactProducts implements Serializable {

@SerializedName("count")
private Integer count;
@SerializedName("results")
private List<Result> results = null;
@SerializedName("total_pages")
private Integer totalPages;
@SerializedName("links")
private Links links;

public Integer getCount() {
    return count;
}

public void setCount(Integer count) {
    this.count = count;
}

public List<Result> getResults() {
    return results;
}

public void setResults(List<Result> results) {
    this.results = results;
}

public Integer getTotalPages() {
    return totalPages;
}

public void setTotalPages(Integer totalPages) {
    this.totalPages = totalPages;
}

public Links getLinks() {
    return links;
}

public void setLinks(Links links) {
    this.links = links;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ContactProducts{" +
            "count=" + count +
            ", results=" + results +
            ", totalPages=" + totalPages +
            ", links=" + links +
            '}';
}

public static class Result {

    @SerializedName("created_at")
    private String createdAt;
    @SerializedName("total_amount")
    private String totalAmount;
    @SerializedName("reference_number")
    private String referenceNumber;
    @SerializedName("is_fee")
    private Boolean isFee;
    @SerializedName("id")
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("products")
    private List<Product> products = null;
    @SerializedName("fee")
    private Fee fee;

    public String getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(String createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public String getTotalAmount() {
        return totalAmount;
    }

    public void setTotalAmount(String totalAmount) {
        this.totalAmount = totalAmount;
    }

    public String getReferenceNumber() {
        return referenceNumber;
    }

    public void setReferenceNumber(String referenceNumber) {
        this.referenceNumber = referenceNumber;
    }

    public Boolean getFee() {
        return isFee;
    }

    public void setFee(Fee fee) {
        this.fee = fee;
    }

    public void setFee(Boolean fee) {
        isFee = fee;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

    public void setProducts(List<Product> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Result{" +
                "createdAt='" + createdAt + '\'' +
                ", totalAmount='" + totalAmount + '\'' +
                ", referenceNumber='" + referenceNumber + '\'' +
                ", isFee=" + isFee +
                ", id=" + id +
                ", products=" + products +
                ", fee=" + fee +
                '}';
    }

    public static class Product {

        @SerializedName("price")
        private String price;
        @SerializedName("description")
        private String description;
        @SerializedName("discount")
        private String discount;
        @SerializedName("pin_code")
        private String pinCode;
        @SerializedName("is_billable")
        private Boolean isBillable;
        @SerializedName("contract")
        private Integer contract;
        @SerializedName("product_type")
        private Integer productType;
        @SerializedName("sale")
        private Integer sale;
        @SerializedName("attribute_product")
        private AttributeProduct attributeProduct;
        @SerializedName("product_type_name")
        private String productTypeName;

        public String getPrice() {
            return price;
        }

        public void setPrice(String price) {
            this.price = price;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        public void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }

        public String getDiscount() {
            return discount;
        }

        public void setDiscount(String discount) {
            this.discount = discount;
        }

        public String getPinCode() {
            return pinCode;
        }

        public void setPinCode(String pinCode) {
            this.pinCode = pinCode;
        }

        public Boolean getBillable() {
            return isBillable;
        }

        public void setBillable(Boolean billable) {
            isBillable = billable;
        }

        public Integer getContract() {
            return contract;
        }

        public void setContract(Integer contract) {
            this.contract = contract;
        }

        public Integer getProductType() {
            return productType;
        }

        public void setProductType(Integer productType) {
            this.productType = productType;
        }

        public Integer getSale() {
            return sale;
        }

        public void setSale(Integer sale) {
            this.sale = sale;
        }

        public AttributeProduct getAttributeProduct() {
            return attributeProduct;
        }

        public void setAttributeProduct(AttributeProduct attributeProduct) {
            this.attributeProduct = attributeProduct;
        }

        public String getProductTypeName() {
            return productTypeName;
        }

        public void setProductTypeName(String productTypeName) {
            this.productTypeName = productTypeName;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Product{" +
                    "price='" + price + '\'' +
                    ", description='" + description + '\'' +
                    ", discount='" + discount + '\'' +
                    ", pinCode='" + pinCode + '\'' +
                    ", isBillable=" + isBillable +
                    ", contract=" + contract +
                    ", productType=" + productType +
                    ", sale=" + sale +
                    ", attributeProduct=" + attributeProduct +
                    ", productTypeName='" + productTypeName + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }

        public static class AttributeProduct {

            @SerializedName("id")
            private Integer id;
            @SerializedName("plan_name")
            private String planName;
            @SerializedName("is_chosen")
            private Boolean isChosen;
            @SerializedName("is_active")
            private Boolean isActive;
            @SerializedName("validity_months")
            private Integer validityMonths;
            @SerializedName("query_quantity")
            private Integer queryQuantity;
            @SerializedName("available_queries")
            private Integer availableQueries;
            @SerializedName("expiration_date")
            private Integer expirationDate;

            public Integer getId() {
                return id;
            }

            public void setId(Integer id) {
                this.id = id;
            }

            public String getPlanName() {
                return planName;
            }

            public void setPlanName(String planName) {
                this.planName = planName;
            }

            public Boolean getChosen() {
                return isChosen;
            }

            public void setChosen(Boolean chosen) {
                isChosen = chosen;
            }

            public Boolean getActive() {
                return isActive;
            }

            public void setActive(Boolean active) {
                isActive = active;
            }

            public Integer getValidityMonths() {
                return validityMonths;
            }

            public void setValidityMonths(Integer validityMonths) {
                this.validityMonths = validityMonths;
            }

            public Integer getQueryQuantity() {
                return queryQuantity;
            }

            public void setQueryQuantity(Integer queryQuantity) {
                this.queryQuantity = queryQuantity;
            }

            public Integer getAvailableQueries() {
                return availableQueries;
            }

            public void setAvailableQueries(Integer availableQueries) {
                this.availableQueries = availableQueries;
            }

            public Integer getExpirationDate() {
                return expirationDate;
            }

            public void setExpirationDate(Integer expirationDate) {
                this.expirationDate = expirationDate;
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return "AttributeProduct{" +
                        "id=" + id +
                        ", planName='" + planName + '\'' +
                        ", isChosen=" + isChosen +
                        ", isActive=" + isActive +
                        ", validityMonths=" + validityMonths +
                        ", queryQuantity=" + queryQuantity +
                        ", availableQueries=" + availableQueries +
                        ", expirationDate=" + expirationDate +
                        '}';
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Fee {

        @SerializedName("fee_amount")
        private String feeAmount;
        @SerializedName("fee_order_number")
        private Integer feeOrderNumber;
        @SerializedName("fee_quantity")
        private Integer feeQuantity;
        @SerializedName("pay_before")
        private String payBefore;
        @SerializedName("status")
        private Integer status;
        @SerializedName("id")
        private Integer id;

        public String getFeeAmount() {
            return feeAmount;
        }

        public void setFeeAmount(String feeAmount) {
            this.feeAmount = feeAmount;
        }

        public Integer getFeeOrderNumber() {
            return feeOrderNumber;
        }

        public void setFeeOrderNumber(Integer feeOrderNumber) {
            this.feeOrderNumber = feeOrderNumber;
        }

        public Integer getFeeQuantity() {
            return feeQuantity;
        }

        public void setFeeQuantity(Integer feeQuantity) {
            this.feeQuantity = feeQuantity;
        }

        public String getPayBefore() {
            return payBefore;
        }

        public void setPayBefore(String payBefore) {
            this.payBefore = payBefore;
        }

        public Integer getStatus() {
            return status;
        }

        public void setStatus(Integer status) {
            this.status = status;
        }

        public Integer getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Fee{" +
                    "feeAmount='" + feeAmount + '\'' +
                    ", feeOrderNumber=" + feeOrderNumber +
                    ", feeQuantity=" + feeQuantity +
                    ", payBefore='" + payBefore + '\'' +
                    ", status=" + status +
                    ", id=" + id +
                    '}';
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Take a look at this website. It might be of help::  http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: @Barns that page helps me generate my model but as I mentioned my model has already been created correctly

Comment: If you need help accessing the value stored in your model, then post the model not the JSON

Comment: try this:: `private Product product = ??? ` ??? because I don't know the rest of your code so you will need to get the `Product` from where you parse the JSON.  Once you have the `Product` object you can get the `AttributeProduct` with `private AttributeProduct attributeProduct = product.getAttributeProduct()`. then you can access the individual attributes with `private String planName = attributeProduct .getPlanName()`  and so on...

Comment: @Barns Well already publish the model is something big. Ok I need to get the data of the model PRODUCT

Comment: @Barns I need to obtain the PRODUCT model, and I corrected my publication

Comment: Same concept just expand it to the classes that are higher on the hierarchy of the model. `Result` appears to be the base class of the `Product` class. Be aware that `Result` has the `Product` class in an `List`

Comment: @PaulOkeke my model have a List<Product>

Comment: I'm trying to understand the problem with this, at what point are you trying to retrieve information from the product class that seems impossible?